# Setting the size of JPanels relative to the size of a Graphics 2D painted grid

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, preferredsize

I have a grid which is place in `firstPanel` and I would like this to fit the ext size of the current, and then the second panel `rightSidePanel` to be placed beside that. However the `firstPanel` extends further than the grid meaning that the `rightSidePanel` appears further away from the grid. Which I do not want. How would I change the size of `firstPanel` I do not care for the re sizing of components - as given by layout managers - as the screen is not re sizable.

[image]

```
package com.aqagame.harrykitchener;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Game 
{

    private JButton moveC1But, moveC2But, rollDiceButton;

    public Game()
    {

        JFrame window = new JFrame ("Main Game");
        final JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1))
        {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {   
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

                super.paintComponent(g2d);

                int width = getWidth() / 4;
                int height = getHeight() / 11;

                for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
                {
                    g.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, 600);
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
                {
                    g.drawLine(0, i * height, 455, i * height);
                }

                g.drawOval(170, 515, 50, 50);
                g.drawOval(240, 515, 50, 50);
                g.drawOval(320, 515, 50, 50);
                g.drawOval(390, 515, 50, 50);
            }
        };

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.add(firstPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel rightSidePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        moveC1But = new JButton("Move Counter 1");
        moveC2But = new JButton("Move Counter 2");
        rollDiceButton = new JButton("Roll Dice");
        rightSidePanel.add(moveC1But, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        rightSidePanel.add(rollDiceButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mainPanel.add(rightSidePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        rightSidePanel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        firstPanel.setBackground(Color.red);

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        window.setSize(800, 600);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);

    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Game();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It will work fine if `JFrame` is re-sizable also.**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    g.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight());
}

for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    g.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height);
}
```

---

--EDIT--

complete code to set the oval also in the center of last row

```
            int ovalSize = 0;
            if (width < height) {
                ovalSize = width;
            } else {
                ovalSize = height;
            }

            int center = (width - ovalSize) / 2;

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                g.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight());
                g.drawOval(i * width + center, height * 10, ovalSize, ovalSize);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                g.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height);
            }
```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: by override getPreferredSize for JPanel

Comment: @mKorbel but if size is not known or frame is re-sizable.

Comment: for this reason is there getPreferredSize, getHeight/Weight always returns proper coordinated (plus/minus max 3pixels == because no one of the LayoutManager cant to divide all numbers in pixles for the childs proportionally)

Comment: I have edited my post. I think its OK to get the width of `JPanel` inside `paintComponent()` method.

Comment: Works absolutely perfect. Setting the ovals to the center is not necessary atm, but thanks.